# Logcat command not working , unable to find app logs

Tags: android, adb, kivy, logcat, android-logcat

Actually i have a bug in my android app which i made and i want to see its logs i followed these commands:-

```
You need to use adb server.
1. Connect your android with your laptop/pc 
2. Go to developer options and turn on the stay awake and USB debugging options. (Your phone) 
3. In your terminal, type "sudo adb kill-server" and then "sudo adb start-server".
4. Type "adb devices" (this should give list of devices connected)
    List of devices attached 
    you_device_name device

5. "cd" to your folder where you have made your build.
6. Type "buildozer android debug deploy run logcat > logcat.txt"
this saves the logs (for the entire process) in a file logcat.txtx in the same folder and also deploys you app on the phone.
Go through it and find your error.
7. keep your phone awake.(do not lock it).
```

All steps performed well but when i come to step no. 6 and run in my terminal, this command stucks there i mean nothing comes up no processing a file gets created in the directory, in which logs are not present:-

logcat.txt

```
# Check configuration tokens
Buildozer is running as root!
This is not recommended, and may lead to problems later.
Are you sure you want to continue [y/n]? # Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20
# Android NDK found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c
# Check application requirements
# Check garden requirements
# Compile platform
# Build the application #102
# Package the application
```

and terminal looks like:-

```
root@kali:~# buildozer android debug deploy logcat > logcat.txt
```

and that;s it nothing comes up after that. Am i doing something wrong? please help

Comment: Did you try `adb logcat`?

Comment: hey it worked, dont know how but when this process goes on "buildozer android debug deploy logcat > logcat.txt". A time came it shows error: device adb not found - waiting for device-. What should i do i searched many times and tried many times but not getting solution

Answer (score 1):

Because of line 284 in .spec file:-

## #(int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)

warn_on_root = 1

It just asks for permission so when it's stuck at this (shown in picture) just type y and hit enter and it will work.

[image]

[image]